# Why does ishandle return 1 for double input?

Tags: matlab, handle

Why does `ishandle` return 1 for double input? For example:

```
>> a = zeros(1, 2);
>> a(1) = line([1 2], [1 2]);

a =
    175.0010         0   

>> ishandle(a)

ans =
    1     1
```

Is there a way to check if a handle is valid that will return 0 for non-handle objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ishandle`  accepts common numeric values like 0 (=desktop handle) and 1 (= first open figure by default) which are often also valid handles. However, **you will still get an error if you try to set to a property that doesn't exist**.

To answer your question either place your code within an exception-handling block:

```
try
   set(a,propName,propValue);
catch
   % do something useful... 
end
```

or , if you know what type of object you're looking for,  replace `ishandle(a)` with (for example):

```
ishandle(a) && strcmp(get(a,'type'),'line')
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab handles are in fact just double precision numbers.  As you use graphics objects (figures, axes, lines etc) Matlab assigns each item a very specific double as a handle.

The `ishandle` function checks to see if the number passed in is serving as a handle to any object which can be represented by a handle.

To demonstrate using figures (which are always assigned integer valued doubles):

```
>> close all;   %Close any open figures
>> ishandle(1)  %Now the value 1 is not a handle
ans =
     0
>> figure(1)    %Open a figure, assign it the value 1
>> ishandle(1)  %Now 1 i a handle
ans =
     1
```

In your example above, the value `0` is always a handle, representing the Matlab root handle object.  This is where some settings related to the command window are held, and it serves as the parent of all figures.  The value 175.xxxx is the handles assigned to the line you drew using the plot command.

One useful trick is the `findobj` function.  It finds all objects which are children of a given object, with parameters matching the input parameters.  For example:

```
h = findobj(0,'type','figure');  Returns all figures
h = findobj(0,'type','line');    Returns all line objects in all figures
h = findobj(1,'type','line');    Returns all line objects in figure 1
h = findobj(1,'type','line','color','r');    Returns all line objects in figure 1 whose color is 'r'.
```